# I want to make .bat file on the desktop that once clicked the file starts django python server, and opens Chrome

Tags: django, batch-file

Make `.bat` file from django that runs the server once clicked and opens chrome browser.

```
@ECHO ON
start cmd.exe /C "python manage.py runserver && cd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\JUDICIARY\ && C:"
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

The `.bat` file opens the chrome browser but it shows 'This site can't be reached' but if I start the server manually then if I open the `.bat` file it opens without problems.

Comment: @shafik did the OP mentionned a virtualenv ?

Comment: 1. Place an empty pair of quotes, like `start "" ...`, because the first encountered quoted string may be used as a window title. 2. Are you sure you want to run `python ...` first and then change the working directory? 3. Do not quote partial paths, quote whole ones, like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`...

Comment: besides the above: quote the whole path, not only parts of it. I know, `C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` will work, but it's bad practice. Always qutoe paths/filenames like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

Comment: @aschipfl - It is never a bad idea to include a quoted title (perhaps empty `""`) as the first argument, but it is only required if the entire command is quoted. Quoting just the middle of the path is a valid way to avoid needing the title argument.

Comment: I don't know how to eliminate your error message. But you don't need START to launch chrome.exe asynchronously. You can simply execute chrome directly from your script, without CMD or START, and the script will resume processing as soon as chrome is launched. I believe you only need START when you are trying to execute a console application asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C "C: && cd C:\youtube\venv\ && .\Scripts\activate && cd .\src && python manage.py runserver "
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

For Mozilla Firefox

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /C "C: && cd C:\youtube\venv\ && .\Scripts\activate && cd .\src && python manage.py runserver "
start C:\"Program Files"\"Mozilla Firefox"\firefox.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
cmd /k "cd /d C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts & activate & python C:\path\to\project\manage.py runserver"
```

or

```
call "C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\activate.bat"
C:\path\to\project\.venv\Scripts\python "C:\path\to\project\manage.py" runserver
```

i think **starting a browser will not work** because the server is still running.

*btw `start firefox.exe "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" starts firefox (or chrome) too.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).